# Can scheduled task actions run in parallel?

Tags: scheduled-task

In windows 10, what is the default behavior when running a scheduled task with two or more actions. Will they run in parallel or will the operating system wait for each actions to finish before starting the next one.

If by default they run sequentially, is there a way to make the actions run in parallel?

Comment: use in the Batch start to run in parallel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-actions) says :

> Be aware that when multiple actions are specified, they are executed sequentially.

There are no official ways to change this behavior, however, you can create multiple scheduled task starting at the same moment, or manage the parallelism on your side with a custom executable/script (batch for example, as suggested in the comments)